# Optimization problems - functions

Tags: derivatives

Here is the question - 
A certain company manufactures $x$ number of chairs a year . The revenue the company received for selling $x$ chairs that year is : $R(x)=200x-0.15x^2$ dollars and the cost incurred by the company for manufacturing $x$ chairs is : $C(x)=4000+6x-0.001x^2$ dollars. Supposed that the profit for the year is $P(x)= R(x) - C(x) $ , then find the production level to maximise the yearly Profit .

This basically means that we have to find the number of chairs,$x$ that should be produced .

I have to solve this using the concept of increasing or decreasing functions / first or 2nd derivative test .

I found -

$R'(x)= 200-0.3x$ -> critical point $(666\frac{2}{3} , 66666\frac{2}{3} ) $

$C'(x)= 6-0.002x$ -> critical point $(3000,13000)$

I'm not too sure on how to find the maximum value of $R(x)$ and minimum value of $C(x) $ to maximise profits only by using the application of 1/2 derivative test .

Comment: Plot the function $P$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that $P(x) = R(x)-C(x)$, so we get $P'(x) = R'(x)-C'(x)$. Then do your analysis of $P'(x)$ the way you did for $R$ and $C$ to find find where $P$ is maximal.

Added: Alternatively, you might note that $P(x)$ is a quadratic function, so your knowledge of quadratic functions may be enough to answer the question (e.g, What is the shape of the graph? Where is the vertex?).

Comment: What is the concept behind setting P'(x) = 0 in order to find maximum x ?

Comment: At a local extremum of $P$, $P'(x)=0$ or $P'(x)$ is undefined.  Your $P$ is a polynomial, so the derivative exists everywhere, so at your local extrema, $P'(x)=0$.  In addition, these $x$ values cut the domain into disjoint intervals, one each of which $P$ is either increasing or decreasing.  But you should really read all this in a calculus book: you can find it in absolutely every one of them.  Cheers!

Comment: @user307640 Hey, was my answer helpful?